# RK4 implementation to solve Lotka Volterra Diff-EQ

Tags: python, python-2.7, runge-kutta

I am trying to understand what's wrong with the code I have butchered together. The code below is one of many implementations I have done today to solve the Lotka Volterra Differential equations (2 Systems), it is the one that I have brought the closest to the desired result.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *



def rk4( f, x0, t ):
    """ 
    4th order Runge-Kutta method implementation to solve x' = f(x,t) with x(t[0]) = x0.

    USE:
        x = rk4(f, x0, t)

    INPUT:
        f     - function of x and t equal to dx/dt. 

        x0    - the initial condition(s).  
                Specifies the value of x @ t = t[0] (initial).  
                Can be a scalar of a vector (NumPy Array)

                Example: [x0, y0] = [500, 20]

        t     - a time vector (array) at which the values of the solution are computed at.
                t[0] is considered as the initial time point 
                h = t[i+1] - t[i] determines the step size h as suggested by the algorithm
                
                Example: t = np.linspace( 0, 500, 200 ), creates 200 time points between 0 and 500
                increasing the number of points in the intervall automatically decreases the step size

    OUTPUT:
        x     - An array containing the solution evaluated at each point in the t array.

    """

    n = len( t )
    x = np.array( [ x0 ] * n )      # creating an array of length n 

    for i in xrange( n - 1 ):
        h = t[i+1] - t[i]           # step size, dependent on the time vector.

        # starting below - the implementation of the RK4 algorithm:
        # for further informations visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge-Kutta_methods

        # k1 is the increment based on the slope at the beginning of the interval (same as Euler)
        # k2 is the increment based on the slope at the midpoint of the interval (with x + 0.5 * k1)
        # k3 is AGAIN the increment based on the slope at the midpoint (with x + 0.5 * k2)
        # k4 is the increment based on the slope at the end of the interval

        k1 = f( x[i], t[i] )
        k2 = f( x[i] + 0.5 * k1, t[i] + 0.5 * h )
        k3 = f( x[i] + 0.5 * k2, t[i] + 0.5 * h )
        k4 = f( x[i] + h * k3, t[i] + h )

        # finally computing the weighted average and storing it in the x-array

        x[i+1] = x[i] + h * ( ( k1 + 2.0 * ( k2 + k3 ) + k4 ) / 6.0 )

    return x

 
# model
 
def model(state,t):
    """
    A function that creates an array containing the Lotka Volterra Differential equation

    Parameter assignement convention:
    a   natural growth rate of the preys
    b   chance of being eaten by a predator
    c   dying rate of the predators per week
    d   chance of catching a prey 
    """

    x,y = state     # will corresponding to initial conditions  
                    # consider it as a vector too 

    a = 0.08
    b = 0.002
    c = 0.2
    d = 0.0004

    return np.array([ x*(a-b*y) , -y*(c - d*x) ]) # corresponds to [dx/dt, dy/dt]
 


################################################################




# initial conditions for the system
x0 = 500
y0 = 20


# vector of times
t = np.linspace( 0, 500, 1000 )

result = rk4( model, [x0,y0], t )
print result


plt.plot(t,result)

plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Population Size')
plt.legend(('x (prey)','y (predator)'))
plt.title('Lotka-Volterra Model')
plt.show()
```

The above code produces the following output

[image]

however if I move the `from pylab import *` code right above the initial conditions I get the correct output

[image]

why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: I believe `rk4` is included in `pylab`. Depending on where you place `import pylab`, it overwrites your `rk4` function with `pylab`'s `rk4`...

Answer (score 1):

`pylab` defines its own implementation of `rk4`, which it takes from `matplotlib`:

```
In [1]: import pylab

In [2]: pylab.rk4
Out[2]: <function matplotlib.mlab.rk4>
```

When you do a wildcard import like `from pylab import *`, you will *override* any local functions with the same name.
In particular, here you're redefining your own `rk4` implementation (ie, the code you've written is never used).

This is why you should **never** do a wildcard import like that.  `pylab` is particularly problematic, in that it defines several functions (such as `any` and `all`) which have *completely different* outputs than the python builtins for certain inputs.

---

Anyway, the root cause of your problem seems to be that your RK4 implementation is incorrect.

You need to use the step size in your calculation of `k_n`.
For example, here's a small snippet of my own RK4 implementation (which, I'll admit, is tuned for speed rather than readability):

```
    while not target(xs):
        ...

        # Do RK4
        self.f(xs, self.k1)
        self.f(xs + halfh*self.k1, self.k2)
        self.f(xs + halfh*self.k2, self.k3)
        self.f(xs + self.h*self.k3, self.k4)

        xs += sixthh*(self.k1 + self.k2 + self.k2 + self.k3 + self.k3 \
                + self.k4)
```

You'll note that the entire state vector is multiplied by `h`, not just the time component.
Try fixing that up in your own code and seeing if the result is the same.

(In my opinion, the habit of wiki etc of treating time as a special case is a cause of a lot of these problems.  Your time vector, `ts`, is simply a special derivative where `t' = 1`.)

---

So for your own code, I believe, but haven't tested, that something like this should work:

```
    k1 = f( x[i], t[i] )
    k2 = f( x[i] + 0.5 * h * k1, t[i] + 0.5 * h )  ## changed to use h
    k3 = f( x[i] + 0.5 * h * k2, t[i] + 0.5 * h )  ## changed to use h
    k4 = f( x[i] + h * k3, t[i] + h )
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I was so hyped when I learned about the universal import that I just kept blindly using it, I have learned my lesson the hard way now. I tried your suggestion and it didn't help my output much, but I will try harder, maybe I find the glitch.

Comment: @Spaced: Just as a side note, universal import is quick and dirty. If you're making a full fledged program, I would avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import pylab
help(pylab.rk4)
```

You'll find a long explanation of the pylab.rk4 command.

This is why it's not a good idea to use `from x import *`.   It's much better to do `import pylab as py`  and then this won't be an issue.

Be aware that even with moving your import command, any later call you might have to `rk4` will fail.